# Use AWS SES as an outbound email gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I would like to re-route all my company outbound emails through AWS SES SMTP, do some processing to the email there, then let it go out once done.
Is this doable ?

This is doable for incoming emails through different types of actions (lambda being one of them), but the docs don't say anything about outbound emails

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think AWS SES supports any kind of outbound filtering at the moment. You will have to pass your outgoing mail through an **internal mail relay** (e.g. EC2 instance or Fargate container running Postfix with your custom filter), do your filtering / processing there, and then pass it on to SES for delivery.

This may also be a preferable solution if you’re sending from multiple sources as in such a case you would need to distribute the SES SMTP credentials to all the sender hosts. That may be impractical.

Better to funnel all your outgoing email through the internal relay (allow access by IP whitelist), do your processing there and then  SES delivers it.

Hope that helps :)